# Questions on using AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am about to start on a personal project built on ASP.NET MVC and I really want to use AngularJS as the front-end framework. Now I have a couple of questions before I start:

1. Is it advisable to use AngularJS for non-SPA web app?
2. Should AngularJS be paired with web API, or will using ASP.NET MVC controllers be ok?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with the .NET MVC controllers and knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using angularJS for non SPA web application is for sure bad practice. AngularJS is heavy library. For non-SPA consider using something like knockout

2) It depends on application design, but I would recommend you to use Restful web-api instead of using actions of `mvc controllers`. asp.net Web-Api controllers is just built for those purposes, so consider using them.